# Loading text into an array when fields are in random order

Tags: array, csv, vbscript

This script reads records from a CSV file of customer names and addresses. The first record of the file is the header (field names); the fields could be in any order, and sometimes have different variations on the field names.

I import the header into a one-dimensional array of field names, and use this loop to assign a variable to each column number:

```
' Read the first line from the file.
  TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine

' Split the line into an array
  arrCustomers = Split(TextLine, ",")

For i = 0 To  UBound(arrCustomers, 1)
    Select Case LCase(arrCustomers(i))                
        case "customer name", "custname", "name"
              CustName  = i
        case "customer number", "custno","custnum"
              CustNo  = i
        case "address", "street"
              Address = i
        case "city" 
              City = i
        case "country"
              Country = i
        case "state"
              State = i
        case else
            ' list of unused fields
            s = s & ", " & arrCustomers(i)
    End Select
Next

msgbox "These fields are unused: " & s
```

For instance, if "Customer Name" is in field 3, then `CustName` = 3 and `arrCustomers(CustName)` is the Customer Name field of the current record.

This loop processes each record:

```
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
  ' Read the first line from the file.    
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
  'Split the line into an array
    arrCustomers = Split(TextLine, ",")        
  'Process the current record
    msgbox "Our customer " & arrCustomers(CustName) & " lives in " & arrCustomers(City) & ", " & arrCustomers(State)
Loop
```

My main problem is that the Case statements in the first loop must include every possible value for the field names. If the address field is called "Address1" or something else I didn't forsee, the `Address` variable becomes 0, and `arrCustomers(Address)` becomes the same as whatever's in the first column.

I suspect that there's a well-known algorithm somewhere for loading an array when the fields could be different each time – one that's better than my method. If not, maybe there's a way to map the "unused fields" on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

A more compact and extensible solution would be to use [pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) to try and take common parts of your field names and use them to map the uneven field headers you get in your csv files.

But I don't think this will work in your case, because you don't seem to have common patterns for all your field names. For instance, `adress` and `street` are field headers that should match to the `Address` field, but as you can see, there's no common usable pattern there. And in cases where there is a common pattern like `cust`, it won't work either because it could be for the fields `CustName` or `CustNo`.

So in this particular case I think you will definitively need to provide the full list of possible field names for each field. Now, you can do this in a more compact way using a [VBScript dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_dictionary_objects.htm) that allows you to check in one line if certain field name (key) exists using `dict.Exists(key)`, or see the field address matching a particular field name using `dict.item(key)`. You still need to add all possible combinations of field names and addresses to the dictionary, but after doing that (just one time), you can use your dictionary very efficiently to get the address for all your headers.